# FB.getLoginStatus has stopped working?

Tags: javascript, facebook

We have a couple of Facebook apps that have been working away for a number of years. Very simple canvas apps. Recently, we decided we want to make some app changes, so I'm trying to install the test version so I can start poking around.

But for some reason, I am being denied. At startup of my app, this Javascript is running:

```
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // Load the Facebook SDK asynchronously
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : appId,   // MY APP ID
            cookie     : true,    // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true,    // parse social plugins on this page
            version    : 'v2.8'   // set default SDK version
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            handleLoginStatusChange(response); 
        });
    };
```

But the call to getLoginStatus consistently returns and object with:

```
authResponse: undefined
status: "undefined"
```

Ok, I think this is a problem with flow... it used to work, but now...

Anyway, the app does this:

a) initialize facebook API

b) call FB.getLoginStatus to determine authentication state

c) if that return "not authorized", I put up the login screen

d) if that returns "connected", I'm doing graph calls

e) if that returns "unknown", I was just printing an error. (I used the example on the Doc page for FB.getLoginStatus).

I have fixed "e)" so that it puts up the login page in that case, and got further into the weeds. My login function calls FB.login, and then goes into the handler again, which gets the "connected" status. That does graph calls to get information about the pages on the account, and then redirects to another page in my (PHP, by the way) app to let the user attach my app to whatever pages he/she wants. But, this redirect - handles the access token (updating if necessary), and then starts over. Initializes the FB API, and calls getLoginStatus. Which again return unknown, even though I just went through the login procedure.

???  This was working, we have the app installed on almost 500 facebook accounts, and is being used currently, I see hits even today.

Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: _“If I can't get past the very initia; FB login, I'm rather sunk”_ – you did not _implement_ login (at least not in the code you have shown.)

Comment: True, sorry for my inexact language. I did implement something that was working fine up until recently.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to login:

```
var permissions = 'public_profile, email, user_friends';
FB.login(null,{scope:permissions});
```

Also, before checking login status, subscribe to the authResponse:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', yourCallback);
```

Comment: Again, I can't even get that far. I have permissions, I have a login button, but having FB draw the login button (at least used to) require that I load the API, then make the "get login status" call. Or at least, that's the way it worked when I wrote this app in August, 2015.

Comment: correction - with a small change, I now go through login, get an access token, save it locally, do some graph calls... then I redirect to the next page in my app, start the same process, and getLoginStatus still returns "unknown", even though I just went through the login process. And this did used to work - the app is installed on almost 500 facebook pages.